# Why start button is not performing the counter functionality

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

Creating a counter

```
def a():    

    def counter_label(label):            
        counter=0
        def count():

            global counter
            counter += 1
            label.config(text=str(counter))
            label.after(1000,count)
        count()

    label=tk.Label(frame,fg="red")
    label.grid(row=0,column=1)

def create_widgets_in_frame():
```

## Creating widgets for the frame

```
    Label(frame,text="TIME:",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)    
    Button(frame,text="START",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command=a,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
    Button(frame,text="STOP",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=E)
    Button(frame,text="EXIT",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command = quit_program,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=E)    

def call_frame_on_top():
    frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

def quit_program():
    root_window.destroy()

root_window=Tk()
root_window.geometry("1500x1000+0+0")
window_width = 1500
window_heigth = 1000
```

## Creating frame inside the root window to hold other GUI elements. All frames must be created in the main program, otherwise they are not accessible in functions.

```
frame=Frame(root_window,bg="blue", width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

## Creating  widgets to  frame

```
create_widgets_in_frame()

root_window.configure(background="blue")
root_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In function `a()` you never actually call the `counter_label`, so it doesn't start the count. And you need to define `counter` variable outside of the function so that you can use `global` keyword.

Here is your code modified:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0                             #Defining counter so you can use it with global
def a():    
    def counter_label(label):            
        counter=0
        def count():
            global counter
            counter += 1
            label.config(text=str(counter))
            label.after(1000,count)
        count()

    label=tk.Label(frame,fg="red")
    label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    counter_label(label)                #Calling the counter_label function

...
```

Comment: Thank you..stevo for your help..You helped right when I needed help most.I appreciate your support.

Comment: I also wanted to include a stop button which will stop the counter and again on pressing the start button,it should start from there where it has stopped.If possible please make the counter in hour:minutes:sec format.I would be grateful to u..